# Issue using a standard controller and an extension

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller-extension

In a VF page I have a table like this :

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!lPrest}" var="prest">

    <apex:column>
        <apex:facet name="header">Prestation</apex:facet>
        <apex:facet name="footer">footer</apex:facet>
        <apex:outputText value="{!prest.Ressource__c}"/>
    </apex:column>

    <apex:column value="{!prest.DO__c}"/>

    <apex:column value="{!prest.nombre_JH__c}">
        <apex:facet name="footer"></apex:facet>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column value="{!prest.TJM_reel__c}">
        <apex:facet name="footer">column footer</apex:facet>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column value="{!prest.TJM_PL__c}">
        <apex:facet name="footer">column footer</apex:facet>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column value="{!prest.CA_total__c}">
        <apex:facet name="footer">column footer</apex:facet>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column value="{!prest.CA_PL__c}">
        <apex:facet name="footer">column footer</apex:facet>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column value="{!prest.CJM_moyen__c}">
        <apex:facet name="footer">column footer</apex:facet>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column value="{!prest.Cout_tot__c}">
        <apex:facet name="footer">column footer</apex:facet>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column value="{!prest.ME_taux__c}">
        <apex:facet name="footer">column footer</apex:facet>
    </apex:column>

  </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

I display this VF on a object layout (non standard opportunity)

For now I use it only with a custom controller like this :

```
public with sharing class Opportunite_PNL_Lightning_Controller {

public List<Prestation__c> lPrest {get;set;}
public Opportunite_custom__c opportunite {get;set;}

public Opportunite_PNL_Lightning_Controller() {
    lPrest = [SELECT Id, Ressource__c, DO__c, nombre_JH__c, TJM_reel__c, TJM_PL__c, CA_total__c, CA_PL__c, ME_taux__c, 
            CJM_moyen__c, Cout_tot__c
            FROM Prestation__c 
            WHERE Opportunite__c = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')
            ORDER BY DO__c];

}

}
```

In this controller I retrive a list of another object, that I display in the table. 
But now I need to retrive the field of the opportuny on which I am (the record displayed) and I want to display some of it's field into the footer of my column.

I try to use the standardController and the extension like that :

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunite_custom__c" extension="Opportunite_PNL_Lightning_Controller">
```

But I got an error when I compile :

> Attribute extension not supported in  in Opportunite_PNL_Lightning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have few syntax error here.

```
 extension="Opportunite_PNL_Lightning_Controller">
```

This will be

```
 extensions="Opportunite_PNL_Lightning_Controller">
```

And also in class you need to change the constructor

```
public with sharing class Opportunite_PNL_Lightning_Controller {

public List<Prestation__c> lPrest {get;set;}
public Opportunite_custom__c opportunite {get;set;}

public Opportunite_PNL_Lightning_Controller(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
 System.debug(stdController.getRecord()); //It will give you current record detail
```